# How to get value of updated column in SQL Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a trigger in SQL that works without errors.  Hwoever it does not accomplish the desired behavior.  What I am trying to do, is when the user updates the field1 column, take that value, and insert that value and the associated information with that value into a different database table.  It does not insert as expected.  Here is the Trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger1]
   ON  [dbo].[table1]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @UpdatedVendId CHAR

    SELECT
      @UpdatedVendId = inserted.VendId
    FROM
      inserted


    IF UPDATE (VendID)
    BEGIN   INSERT INTO OtherTable (ClassID, Crtd_User, LUpd_DateTime, LUpd_User, VendId) SELECT ClassID, crtd_User, LUpd_DateTime, LUpd_User, VendId FROM dbo.table1 WHERE VendId = @UpdatedVendId

    END
END
```

Comment: Your trigger is not set based. Drop the scalar variables and simply do your insert from the inserted virtual table.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem you have with multiple row operation you can greatly simplify your trigger by using the inserted virtual table. The **entire** contents of your trigger can be shortened to this.

```
IF UPDATE (VendID)
    INSERT INTO OtherTable 
    (
        ClassID
        , Crtd_User
        , LUpd_DateTime
        , LUpd_User
        , VendId
    ) 
    SELECT t1.ClassID
        , t1.crtd_User
        , t1.LUpd_DateTime
        , t1.LUpd_User
        , t1.VendId 
    FROM dbo.table1 t1
    join inserted i on i.ClassID = t.ClassID
```

Comment: This did not seem to work for me.  It did not insert any record into the database as expected.  I am trying to figure out if it did not like the JOIN in the insert statement